# Can QGIS fetch data/ rip from a WMTS server - then serve them as a WMTS server?

Tags: qgis-server, wmts

The source server serves tiles using EPSG:32633  - I need a server with EPSG:3857. Can QGIS somehow rip the data, then re-tile it and serve it as EPSG:3857?

Comment: When a service uses another service as a data input this is known as cascading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about QGIS Server but I would recommend a tool called [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org/).

*Other features: offer projections that your sources do not support*

Another solution could be the proxy functionality of [Geoserver](https://docs.geoserver.org/2.22.x/en/user/data/cascaded/wmts.html).